# How to add html in angularjs coming in string format?

Tags: angularjs

This function `getStudentsNames(item.students);` is returning a string as `<br>Rom<br>Jay Clayton<br>Rom roy<br>`.

I tried replacing `<br>` with `\n` but didn't have any effect. I'm not able to get a line break so if any one could help. Thanks.

```
<span class="tooltiptext">{{getStudentsNames(item.students);}}</span>
```

Comment: can be fixed using css

Comment: No it's not a kind of  problem that can be fixed using css Burak's answer worked for me

Comment: Sure it can if all you want is line breaks. Read up on css `white-space` property

Comment: An example would be a better option as I'm a kind of newbie.

Comment: a google search would take you to css docs that would show examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) for this.

```js
angular.module("app",[]).controller("ctrl",function($scope){

  $scope.htmlData = "<br>Rom<br>Jay Clayton<br>Rom roy<br>";
  
  $scope.getStudentsNames = function(){
      return this.htmlData;
  }

}).filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce) {
 return function(text) {
  return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
 };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<span ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" class="tooltiptext" ng-bind-html="getStudentsNames() | to_trusted"></span>
```

Comment: Any way besides using filter I've already added a lot of code for a small function.BTW thanks

Comment: The filter is just for security. ng-bind-html does the job

Answer (score 0):

Try [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive.It evaluates the expression and inserts the resulting HTML into the element in a secure way.

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.HTMLString = "<br>Rom<br>Jay Clayton<br>Rom roy<br>";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-bind-html="HTMLString"></div>
</div>
```